# TempDB Initial Size resetting even after change

Tags: sql, sql-server

One of my tempdb's has a data file size of 60GB. I shrunk the file down to 2GB, then set the initial size to 2GB. The data file shrink is successful. When I go back into the db properties for tempdb, it shows initial size of 60000MB again. I've tried setting it to 4GB too and that still resets to 60000MB. This is very frustrating, since every time the service restarts, that tempdb data file is set to 60GB using up a lot of space.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

how did you "shrink" the filesize?  If there are 60GB worth of entries, the table should "auto-size" to allow room for all entires.

Comment: Right click, Tasks, Shrink, Files, select data file, then reorg pages before releasing unused space, shrink to 2,000 MB. I believe this process just uses DBCC SHRINKFILE. It does work, as it shrinks the data file, but it just balloons up again, but only uses 10MB of space.